# How to make tag for chrome extension in webstore

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, chrome-web-store

I have done a extension for one specific website and uploaded it in my webstore developer account and published it.

After that if i try to search that extension in webstore it is not listing.

Any idea on this? Am i want to make any tag or something in my extension?

PS:

Here is an example of my scenario.  I have created a extension for the website abcd.com and named the extension as "abcd - do action".  When i search in webstore for abcd, its listing some of the extensions but not mine.

Answer (score 0):

The Chrome Web Store index is updated on a delayed basis. Sometimes it can take a few hours or a few days before your item is searchable. You should also try searching without your own extension installed as sometimes the Chrome Web Store will hide installed extensions from results.

Comment: Thanks abraham. I will wait for some days